# How can I use fixed width integer in Windows Forms Applications (C++)

Tags: c++, winforms, bit-shift

I have a Windows Forms Application with an input field. I separate the user input and put it in a vector, then change it to doubles. After that I call a function that calculates the logarithm but the fixed width integers I use get rounded/cut off in the Windows Forms app (this does not happen in the console). Even when I try to define one in the Forms header itself it will be cut off, however I want to output the correct number in my Forms app, not only the console app.

```
uint16_t log2(uint32_t n) {
if (n == 0) return 0;
uint16_t logValue = -1;
while (n) {
    logValue++;
    n >>= 1;
}
return logValue;
}
```

For example when i input '10' the output should be 3.3219280948873623478703194294894 (it's rounded but you get the point) and it works in my console app (that I use for testing all my functions) however when I transfer it to my Forms Application it just outputs 3 (or 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8... without any of the missing decimal places with different input).

Comment: @nicomp I know, that's why I convert it (as stated above)

Comment: Please give an example of it going wrong.  What is the input?  What is the output you got?  What is the output you wanted?

Comment: @BenVoigt Well it's just cut off. For example when i input '10' the output should be 3.3219280948873623478703194294894 (it's rounded but you get the point) and it works in my console app (that I use for testing all my functions) however when I transfer it to my Forms Application it just outputs 3 (or 0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8... without any of the missing decimal places).

Comment: @BenVoigt Also it doesn't matter. Even manually  entering a fixed width integer will result in it being cut off.

Comment: You're expecting `logValue` to contain `3.3219`... ?  Even apart from the fact that it can't, because it is an integer type, the first time through your loop `logValue` is `-1` and `logValue++` changes it to `0`.  Next time through the loop, `logValue++` changes it to `1`.  Then `2` and `3`.  There are no intermediate values created by `++` ever.

Comment: If it "works" in your console app, it is because your console app is using a library logarithm function, and not the code in your question.

Comment: @BenVoigt this is the function I'm using: `uint16_t log2(uint32_t n) {

 if (n == 0)
 {
  return 0;
 }
 uint16_t logValue = -1;
 while (n) {
  logValue++;
  n >>= 1;
 }
 return logValue;
}`

Comment: There is absolutely no way that function is giving you `3.3219`...   You've made an unfortunate choice to write a function with the exact same name as [a library function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2).  Pick a unique name.

Answer (score 0):

> the output should be 3.3219280948873623478703194294894 and it works in my console app

You have a name collision between your `log2` function and the Standard library `std::log2()`.  Since [the library function is provided for all integral types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2), it is a better match when both are found by name resolution.

Change your function to a unique name, then your WinForms and console testing results will both reflect its actual behavior (of returning an integer).